# Why am I not able to post a new question from my another account?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, post-ban

I want to post a question to Stack Overflow, but I get the following error when I try to submit it:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

This happens under my other user name, which is `Gitesh Dang`.

I am new to this site; how is it possible for me to ask questions?
Please tell me the reason for this error.
My team is already using this site.

You can see my profile [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437595/gitesh-dang).  I have been using this site for approximately the last 10 days.

Please tell me the reason I cannot put my new question on the site.

Comment: what is the exact message you're seeing?

Comment: Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

     Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

this is giving after i click post button to submit my question

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No further questions are being accepted from your account due to a history of poor questions, as measured by the downvotes you've received on Stack Overflow.  See Jeff's answer to [Can we prevent some of the low-quality questions from entering our system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294).

Comment: but i am able to comment on other question and i am also able to give answers to other question..how

Comment: @Ricky: Yes. You are only prevented from *asking new questions*.

Comment: By giving best answers can i make my account able for putting new questions..

Comment: @Ricky: I don't know. Why don't you try? Good answers provide more rewards than simply being able to ask questions.

Comment: thanks but can i delete my this account to create again.pls

Comment: @Ricky, it might be easier for you to edit your existing questions to improve them; then you can continue using your existing account and keep the 35 reputation you have earned with it.

Comment: @Ricky: The ban is tied to your IP address.

Comment: what type edition...what should i edit..can you pls help me to edit my questions.?

Comment: I will learn more from this site and have learnt also...

Comment: @Ricky: Some advice: try reading your questions as if you were someone attempting to answer it. Have you provided all the information necessary for an intelligent answer? Have you made an attempt to solve the problem yourself, and if so, what, specifically, is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: @Ricky: Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Can i delete that all questions.?

Comment: @Ricky: you can, but it won't make a difference - downvotes from deleted questions are factored into the ban.  Really, though, rather than trying to find a way around the ban, why don't you try to improve your questions? That's really your best shot. Read the article Jon linked to: lots of good tips in there.

Comment: I am trying to edit but i am not understanding how can i edit i mean what should i edit. I have put my questions according to my need. Sir, I am not understanding what should i edit. It seems like a clear to me according to my need to put that questions.

Comment: Please Sir please help.Can the meta of stack overflow reset my account.

Comment: I request to reset my account.. please